# Editable Span disappears from DOM in Edge

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, contenteditable

I have the following style:

```
<style>
    span{
        display:inline-block;
        width:200px;
        border:solid 1px;
    }
</style>
```

and my html:

```
Type something, select it, then hit Del <span contenteditable="true"></span>
```

When using Edge: if I type something in the span, selected the text, then hit the Del key, the span disappears. When I say disappears, I mean when I examine the element in the debugger, it no longer exists in the DOM. This happens with Edge and does not happen with Chrome or Firefox. The expected behavior is that the text would clear but the span would be as it was prior to typing the text. If anyone knows of a simple way of preventing this, I would appreciate it.

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dxsvwz3f/2/

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

This is acknowledged as a bug:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/18787906/

Comment: Were you able to find any workaround till the time it is fixed. Facing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

This is because Microsoft DevTools has a shortcut key defined for it.

[image]

You may also refer the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/elements

Comment: OK, but this happens without the DevTools open.

Comment: Well I could not reproduce your problem (without DevTools open). Might be a installation bug or some overridden setting. Can you try reinstalling/updating Edge.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'll try it on another machine.

Comment: I just tried it on another computer and got the same result. To be clear, you must select the entire text. If I leave one character behind, only the selected text is gone, as expected. Thanks for trying.

Comment: OK, I just managed to do the right google, and found that Microsoft acknowledges this to be a bug.

Comment: Can you post the link here?